# System.IndexOutOfRangeException - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, outofrangeexception

I am creating a program that imports a 2d object array of information from an excel sheet. It then passes this array to ProcessObjects method to be processed and printed/exported back out to an excel template.Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error message?

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Project.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
private void ProcessObjects(object[,] classesArray, object[,] classesAvailabilityArray, Excel.Workbook workbook2, Excel.Sheets excelSheets)
{
    // once classes are selected, they are copied to a temporary location
    // while they're waiting to be printed
    object[,] tempArray = new object[6,3];

    // This stops the while loop once enough credit hours have been taken 
    // It must reach 123 hours for CS Degree .
    int hourCounter = 0;

    int iteration = 0;

    while (hourCounter < 123)
        {
            // this while loop copies some classes from classesArray to tempArray
            // so they can be printed into the excel template (NewStudentTemplateCS.xlsx)
            //
            int classes = 0, hours = 0; // stops while loop if limit is reached
            int w = 0, x = 0; // used to select individual elements of tempArray (0 based)
                              // w = row
                              // x = column
            int y = 1, z = 1; // used to select individual elements of classesArray (1 based)
                              // y = row
                              // z = column
            while(classes < 7 || hours < 17)
            {
                // this loop checks the status of the flag and stops at the first avaliable
                // class/row of classesArray
                while (classesArray[y,7] == (object)1)
                {
                    y++;
                }

                // copies the call EX: "MATH 2313" from classesArray to tempArray
                tempArray[w,x] = classesArray[y,z];
                x += 2;
                z += 2;
                // copies the name EX: "Calculus I" from classesArray to tempArray
                tempArray[w, x] = classesArray[y, z];
                x++;
                z++;
                // Copies the hours EX: "3" from classesArray to tempArray
                tempArray[w, x] = classesArray[y, z];

                Console.WriteLine("debug test");

                // increments classes, hours, and hourCounter for exit decision
                classes += 1;
                hours += (int)classesArray[y, z];
                hourCounter += (int)classesArray[y, z];

                // sets flag to one
                z += 3;
                classesArray[y, z] = 1;

            }// end while loop

            // print method that prints temp array and clears tempArray for next use
            PrintArray(tempArray, iteration, workbook2, excelSheets);

            // iterates iteration
            iteration++;

        } // end while loop
        // print method that prints temp array and clears tempArray for next use
        PrintArray(tempArray, iteration, workbook2, excelSheets);

        // iterates iteration
        iteration++;

    } // end while loop
} // end ProcessObjects method
```

I have commented out each of the following lines individually, but each line of code all returns the same error I listed above.

```
Console.WriteLine("debug test");

// increments classes, hours, and hourCounter for exit decision
classes += 1;
hours += (int)classesArray[y, z];
hourCounter += (int)classesArray[y, z];

// sets flag to one
z += 3;
classesArray[y, z] = 1;
```

Comment: Well, what happens if you debug it?  Is there some reason why you cannot break at the first line of code and then single-step through, run to more breakpoints or run to cursor to find out where the problem is with some index?  We have no idea what test data you are calling it with.  Just debug it!

Comment: from your question we can only tell the array dimension of the tempArray, my guess is that classesArray is not large enough.Show us how you declare and populate classesArray?

Answer (score 3):

Step through your code in the debugger:

```
object[,] tempArray = new object[6,3];
```

You are creating an array with max indexes at `tempArray[5, 2]`. Then you start looping. At the start of each loop:

```
int w = 0, x = 0;
```

Then in the body of the loop:

```
tempArray[w,x] = classesArray[y,z];
```

You assign to `tempArray[0, 0]`

```
x += 2;
z += 2;
tempArray[w, x] = classesArray[y, z];
```

You assign to `tempArray[0, 2]`

```
x++;
z++;
// Copies the hours EX: "3" from classesArray to tempArray
tempArray[w, x] = classesArray[y, z];
```

You assign to `tempArray[0, 3]`. But the maximum index of `tempArray` is [0, 2]; your array index is out of range, exactly what the exception was telling you.

If you can be certain that `y` and `z` can never go outside the bounds of `classesArray`, you can declare `tempArray` like this:

```
object[,] tempArray = new object[classesArray.GetLength(0), classesArray.GetLength(1)];
```

But with all those hard-coded magic numbers, and trying to synchronize arrays with differing bases, this is very risky code.

Comment: .and difficult to read.  I cannot understand why there are comments that explain what the 'xyzzy' indexes are, but the index names are just sequential alpha characters. if '//w = row' whay not call the variable 'row'?

Comment: @ Dour High Arch- Thanks for the help. I'm just mentally and logically exhausted; i've been staring at the same code for 12+ hrs. The reason for the hard code is I only need to print out specific columns of the array; the rest is just for background error checking that will not be displayed. I figured out the hard way that the bases were different; i would have made them the same base by choice if I knew the language better. This is my first project in C#, so its probably not as efficient as a skilled programmer.

Comment: @ Martin James I did correct the wxyz indexes in the PrintArray for better readability; i just didn't correct it in this code

Answer (score 1):

The integers you are using (i.e. w,x,y,z) are becoming bigger than the defined array size. You should add breakpoints into the code so you can see what is happening during compiling and see where they are becoming bigger than expected by the array definitions.

The rules of your loop, generally, are used to stop index out of bounds exceptions occurring. I would suggest breaking up the code a bit, there seems to be a lot of stuff going on, but it seems to be too much for this loop.